# Why did they use a fake name "Lucy" for Barry Seal's wife?

Tags: american-made

As per the movie  [*American Made*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3532216/)  the name of Barry's wife is Lucy... where actually her name was Deborah Seal.

Why did they rename her Lucy in the movie?

Answer (score 2):

Like the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Made_(film)) says:

> Lucy is **loosely** based on Barry Seal's third wife Deborah.

So, as any movie that is based on real events, some of the events portrayed in the movies are not always exactly like the real ones.

I think this is the case for the wife, in real life Barry Seal's wife is called **Deborah** and she is **brunette**, and in the movie she is called **Lucy** and she is **blonde**.

Even Movie Barry is not exactly like Real life Barry, the characters are only *inspired* by the stories.